# Upload an image to google drive using Apps Script from an app using post file method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using Apps Script. I have used web in Android app. I am posting file with my app but I don't know how to save that file to Google Drive. Please suggest me the Apps Script code.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Are you trying to use a webapp to upload your file from your android app?

Answer (score 1):

the gs:

```
function uploadFile(obj) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Here');
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1VAh2z-LD6nHPuHzgc7JlpYnPbOP_ch33');
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty('FileName'))obj['FileName']="NoFileName";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(obj.bytes, obj.mimeType, obj.FileName);
  var rObj={};
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyMMddHHmmss");
  var file=folder.createFile(blob).setName(obj.FileName + '_' + ts);
  rObj['file']=file;
  rObj['filename']=file.getName();
  rObj['filetype']=file.getMimeType();
  rObj['id']=file.getId();
  if(obj.Destination!=0){
    var uObj={albumid:obj.Destination,fileid:rObj.id,filename:rObj.filename};
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(uObj));
    addFileToPhotoLibrary(uObj);
    var msg=Utilities.formatString('<br/>File: %s<br />Type: %s<br />Folder: %s<br />File Added to Photo Library',rObj.filename,rObj.filetype,folder.getName());
    return msg;
  }else{
    var msg=Utilities.formatString('<br/>File: %s<br />Type: %s<br />Folder: %s',rObj.filename,rObj.filetype,folder.getName());
    return msg;
  }
}
```

The js:

```
function uploadFile(form) {
    console.log('form.elements.Destination.value= %s',form.elements.Destination.value);
    console.log('form.elements.FileName.value= %s',form.elements.FileName.value);
    $('#msg').css('display','block');
    $('#msg').html('UpLoading...Please Wait');
    const file=form.File.files[0];
    const fr=new FileReader();
    fr.onload=function(e) {
      const obj={FileName:form.elements.FileName.value,Destination:form.elements.Destination.value,mimeType:file.type,bytes:[...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]};
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
        $('#msg').css('display','block');
        $('#msg').html(msg);
      })
      .uploadFile(obj);
    }
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
```

the html:

```
<form>
  <br /><select id="sel1" name="Destination"></select> Upload Destination
  <br /><input type="text" name='FileName' /> File Name
  <br /><input type="file" name='File'; />
  <br /><input type="button" value="Upload" onClick="uploadFile(this.parentNode);" />
  <br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
</form>
<div id="msg"></div>
```